# Importing large sqlite database to tableview and updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, uitableview

Note: I have very little knowledge of C or IOS development.

I have a small sqlite database (110Kb), with around 700 records. I would like to know the best way to import them into a Tableview. 
Also, how when I click on a cell, the application moves to another ViewController and uses the data from the Tableview to update the database file depending on whether the sign in or out button is used.
So far I have found this website (I have just downloaded the project) and have used this to try and learn something:
http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-How-To-Display-SQLite-Data-in-a-UITableView
Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Code for .m file to insert records to tableview:

```
//  AuthorVC.m


#import "AuthorVC.h"
#import "Author.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>


@implementation AuthorVC
@synthesize theauthors;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self authorList];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.theauthors count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AuthorsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    int rowCount = indexPath.row;

    Author *author = [self.theauthors objectAtIndex:rowCount];
    cell.textLabel.text = author.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = author.title;


    return cell;
}


-(NSMutableArray *) authorList{
    theauthors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AuthorsDb.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        }


        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM  books";
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }else{

            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                Author * author = [[Author alloc] init];
                author.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
                author.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
                author.genre = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];
                [theauthors addObject:author];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return theauthors;
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Being honest this is quite a bit of work and not something easily exampled in a Stack Overflow answer. There are two places you should look to examples of something similar to your requirement.

[Apple CoreData recipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html)
This is very close to what you need. Read and have a play with the project they provided to get an understanding of what is needed and how much work is involved.

Also:
[Ray Wenderlich CoreData Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)
This will give you a more gentle introduction to CoreData and how to transition from one view to another. The tutorial is step by step with explanations and suit any level of experience.

Ray also has great tutorials on how to talk to servers which would be handy to see for you to learn how to update a database via an api call.

Hope this helps a bit. You have to just dive in and get your hands dirty to learn.

Comment: Thanks for this, it saves lots of googling :). Would what I am asking be possible?

Comment: Yes sure, it wouldn't be fair to just paste a load of code for you to copy here especially as you wouldn't really learn anything. The best way to learn is have a solid approach. You know what you are wishing to achieve, note the steps needed and then work out how to do those steps. Thats what us professionals do every day.